# Automatically close old Xterm window when opening a new one

Tags: xterm

I am looking for a command that I can add to my .Xresources file, that basically only allows one unique xterm window. When I open a new one I want the old one to close. I couldnt find it through google, so I am not sure a command like this exists.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Why would you want to do that?